# Do the PostgreSQL pg_* catalog tables respect transactions?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, isolation-level

Do the pg_* catalog tables and the `has_table_privilege` function respect transaction isolation levels? Say in a default READ COMMITTED transaction, does the below have a race condition?

```sql
SELECT
  schemaname,
  tablename
FROM
  pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE
  has_table_privilege(
    'a_role_name',
    quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename),
    'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER'
  ) = true
```

Specifically is this possible - a table in `pg_catalog.pg_tables` get selected, the table is deleted by another connection, and then the `has_table_privilege` function errors since the table no longer exists.

The reason why asking - it looks like that's what happen when we delete a table when (a more complex form of) the above query is running. Occasionally, we see errors like

```
relation "my_schema.my_table" does not exist
```

If this is the case - how best to choose existing tables where a user has privileges on it, without running into this error?